# How to access the microSD card on Asus Transformer?

Tags: external-sd, asus-eee-pad-transformer

Is it possible to access the microSD card on an Asus Transformer or is there some way to mount this so it is accessible remotely?

When connected via USB to a PC the SD card in the keyboard dock is available but the microSD card in the main tablet is not.

I have read some articles for similar Android devices which mention that the microSD card is mounted but I can't seem to see it.

It would be good to not have to remove the microSD from the main tablet every time I want to copy files to it since ejecting it isn't exactly easy!

*Edit* I've used the rather nice http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/ FTP tool, from this I can't see the microSD card either.

*Edit Part Deux* I've actually returned the Asus Transformer as there were too many problems with it, whether these were Asus problems or Honeycomb problems I couldn't determine. *caveat emptor*

Comment: I'm not familiar with this device, is the dock required to connect it to the PC?

Comment: @Matthew if you mean the keyboard dock then no, this isn't required to connect the device to the PC, both the keyboard dock and the tablet itself have an iPod-esque connector with a USB connector at the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way (but one that inquires a small cost) is to use something like [WiFi File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dooblou.WiFiFileExplorerPRO&feature=search_result). The free version allows you to download files from a device on the same network as your PC, the pro version enables uploading and downloading directories.

[image: Wifi File Explorer]
<sup>Wifi File Explorer (click image to enlarge)</sup>

As for reading the SD card directly from the computer, i haven't found anything that gives instructions on how to do this. But if i find anything, i'll let you know!

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is that the microSD card is not being offered as a directory at all, I've used the rather excellent http://code.google.com/p/swiftp/ to transfer files, but can't see the micro SD card from this either.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have to power down and back up for the card to be recognized.  Asus says you don't have to do that but if you don't it will not see the card.  Typical of how terrible Asus is at supporting this tablet.